# Error while importing tensorflow: No module named tensorflow.tsl

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

I've working on RNN_LSTM and the codes were working well just a month ago, but now gives errors, I tried to fix but no result....

Found out the error is on TensorFlow
I installed successfully but can't import it

```
!pip Install TensorFlow

Successfully installed google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.6 keras-2.8.0 tensorboard-2.8.0 tensorboard-data-server-0.6.1`
```

```py
Import Tensorflow as tf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:37
     34 import sys as _sys
     35 import typing as _typing
---> 37 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     38 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     40 # Make sure code inside the TensorFlow codebase can use tf2.enabled() at _descriptor_pool.Default().AddSerializedFile(b'\n*tensorflow/core/protobuf/rpc_options.proto\x12\x10tensorflow.dummy\x1a)tensorflow/tsl/protobuf/rpc_options.protoBWZUgithub.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go/core/protobuf/for_core_protos_go_protoP\x00\x62\x06proto3')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.tsl'
```

Comment: Hi @Sana Isam, Please let us know which TensorFlow and python version you are using. It seems TensorFlow has not installed in your system correctly. Could you please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) and follow the step by step instructions mentioned to install tensorflow. Let us know if the issue still persists.